# Python - how to populate a list of dictionaries from existing lists

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a `list` of lists, e.g. `mylist=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],...]`, and I want to populate a `list` of `dict`s where the values of the dicts come from the nested lists, e.g.

```
dlist[0]['area']=1
dlist[0]['volume']=2
dlist[0]['height']=3
dlist[1]['area']=4
dlist[1]['volume']=5
```

etc.

So far I have:

```
dlist = [{'area':mylist[i][0], 'volume':mylist[i][1], 'height':mylist[i][2]} for i in range(len(mylist)]
```

My lists can be very large in the first dimension (i.e. `len(mylist)` can be very large). Is there a faster way than this list comprehension? Maybe something with `zip`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `zip` in a `list` comprehension:

**Code:**

```
keys = ('area', 'volume', 'height')
output = [dict(zip(keys, l)) for l in mylist]
```

**Data:**

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

**Results:**

```
[{'volume': 2, 'height': 3, 'area': 1},
 {'volume': 5, 'height': 6, 'area': 4},
 {'volume': 8, 'height': 9, 'area': 7}]
```

**But if you want faster than your original solution:**

Then skip the `zip`, use iteration on your original `list`, and build the `dict` directly:

```
output = [{'area': i[0], 'volume': i[1], 'height': i[2]} for i in mylist]
```

**Timing Code:**

```
import timeit

mylist = [[1, 2, 3]] * 100000

def method1():
    keys = ('area', 'volume', 'height')
    return [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in mylist]

def method2():
    return [{
        'area': mylist[i][0],
        'volume': mylist[i][1],
        'height': mylist[i][2]
    } for i in range(len(mylist))]

def method3():
    return [{'area': i[0], 'volume': i[1], 'height': i[2]} for i in mylist]

print(timeit.repeat("method1()", "from __main__ import method1", number=10))
print(timeit.repeat("method2()", "from __main__ import method2", number=10))
print(timeit.repeat("method3()", "from __main__ import method3", number=10))
```

**Timing Results:**

Zip:

```
[1.192184281360701, 1.7045185775655127, 1.2134081278821043]
```

Original:

```
[0.38957559529443664, 0.38713287436332866, 0.3920681133687083]
```

Iterate on list, build dict directly:

```
[0.2965552921248671, 0.28165834370140264, 0.29972900470716013]
```

Comment: Neat, thanks, but this runs a bit slower than the original.

Comment: Editted with faster, not `zip`

Comment: Method 3 for the win, better style and performance than what I had. Thanks!